# There are a couple unused megabytes after partition has been wiped

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, storage

I was trying to erase my partition and reinstall OS X but it says that 108.35 out of 108.50 gigabytes are being used, I'm just curious on what they are used for and why is there space still being used even if the disk has been wiped.

Comment: You erased the disk and all but 150 MB are still in use? I don't think the disk was erased correctly. Even a full-blown OS install is only about 20-30 GB.

Comment: did you do a quick erase? I believe theres  a more thorough option, that will make sure to completely erase the disk.

Answer (score -1):

Every drive is different when it comes to the amount of space that it takes for it's own use.

For me, I have a 128GB SSD in my MacBook Air, but if I look up the amount of space available to me it usually shows that I have 120-121GB of actual usable space.

Comment: No, every disk is the same. if they aren't they'd fail QC.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but ok. When a hard drive is made, the manufacturer sets aside space that the hard drive uses for itself, no drive will ever allow you to have the full capacity that it shows on the box. I forget what it's called exactly but there is a name for it. My drive only show up as a 121GB drive even though I purchased a computer with 128GB drive. Then on top of the OP had reinstalled OS X, and that takes up space as well.

Comment: why would they do that? why would they store it on the hard drive? that data will be stored on either the main controller chip, or an external flash IC.

Comment: That's just the way it is. It happens with everything be it hard drives or flash drives or whatever. It also occurs because of how bytes translate when the OS actually reads the drive.

Comment: what makes you think that?

Comment: Because that is how I learned it and what I have seen in all my work. I am a computer science major graduate. If you want to learn more, look up why hard drives show less space.

Comment: Oh, it just doesn't make sense that they would store important data on the hard drive. EDIT: do you mean swap?

Comment: No not swap. It may not make sense, but that's what manufacturers do; again at least by the way my professors explained it.